# Аналог cURL'овского '-u' на Java

Tags: curl, java

Привет!

Нужно получить JSON с сервера. В официальном примере для этого указана команда cURL:

```
curl -u id:key http:/foo.bar -d 'grant=otp'
```

А мне нужно сделать это на Java. Пишу код:

```
DefaultHttpClient mClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost mRequest = new HttpPost("http://foo.bar");
mRequest.addHeader("grant", "otp");
HttpResponse mResponse = mClient.execute(mRequest);
...
```

То есть у меня получилось заменить параметр `-d '...'` в cURL на `addHeader(...)` в Java, но никак не могу заменить `-u ...`.

Есть ли вообще аналог такого `-u` на Java?

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл решение.

```
String user = "user";
String password = "password";

String joined = user + ":" + password;
String base64 = java.util.Base64.Encoder.encodeToString(joined.getBytes());

String auth_title = "Authorization";
String auth_value = "Basic " + base64;
```

И далее добавляем заголовок в запрос:

```
mRequest.addHeader(auth_title, auth_value);
```